# Квадратные скобки в json

Tags: c#

С api сайта получаю json, но он заключён в [], что делает невозможным дальнейшую работу с ним. Как убрать [] и получить чистый json код?

Comment: Квадратные скобки - это массив, если они есть, то вы получаете в итоге что то на подобие `MyObject[]`. Просто укажите нужный тип и все!

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так, полагаю, выглядит ваш json:

```
[{
    "Name":"John",
    "Age":30,
    "Cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
},
{
    "Name":"John",
    "Age":30,
    "Cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
}]
```

Это класс, который его описывает:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<string> Cars { get; set; }
}

var personArray = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person[]>(json);
```

Этой строкой десериализуем json, где Person[] - массив классов Person (там так же может быть другой тип данных, и не обязательно массив), а json это строка, получаемая с помощью api сайта (тип string).

```
Console.WriteLine(personArray[0].Name);
```

Получаем поле первого объекта в массиве из десериализованного json

На основе готового json, модель класса можно создать с помощью json2csharp.